# how can I add onclick or eventListener while appending a button using javascript

Tags: javascript, bootstrap-4

well I am trying to append a button when user clicks an add button, also the button which is getting appended should have an onclick attribute or eventListener() to call deleteMyOrder() so how can I achieve this?
I have done the following thing but it is still not working:

```
<body>
<div id="insertHere"> </div>
<input type="button" value="addButton" onclick="myFunc()" />

<script>
function myFunc()
{
var cell4 = document.getElementById('insertHere');
var element3 = document.createElement("input");
element3.type = "button";
element3.name = "add";
element3.id = "forRemove";
element3.value="Remove";
element3.className="btn btn-outline-danger btn-sm";
element3.onclick = "deleteMyOrder()";
cell4.appendChild(element3);
}
```

Comment: element3.addEventListener('click', () => {
  deleteMyOrder()
})

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can add event listener on the dynamically created button like this

```
element3.addEventListener('click', () => { console.log('button clicked') })
```

```html
<body>
<div id="insertHere"> </div>
<input type="button" value="addButton" onclick="myFunc()" />

<script>
function myFunc()
{
  var cell4 = document.getElementById('insertHere');
  var element3 = document.createElement("input");
  element3.type = "button";
  element3.name = "add";
  element3.id = "forRemove";
  element3.value="Remove";
  element3.className="btn btn-outline-danger btn-sm";
  element3.addEventListener('click', () => { 
      console.log('button clicked');  // your click action here
    })
  cell4.appendChild(element3);
   
}
</script>
```