# EventListener not firing - Dynamically create and download calendar event

Tags: javascript, tampermonkey, userscripts

I am getting the plain text of outlook calendar events and converting them to an ics for download with Tampermonkey.

The button worked when I wrote this a couple of years ago, but now it is not. I am not sure if I need to grant permissions now or if something else broke it. The button is added just fine, but I can't get the event listener to fire.

```js
// .....
// @grant        none
//=====    convert text only calendar to a donwloadable ICS file
elementReady('#desc-content').then((element) => {
  //grab the relevant text
  if (element.innerHTML.includes("BEGIN:VCALENDAR")) {
    //clean up some bit
    var calendar = element.innerHTML.substring(0, element.innerHTML.length - '<div class="clearfix"></div>'.length).replace(/<br\s*[\/]?>/gi, '\n');
    //Create a button element 
    var CalendarEventButton = document.createElement("button");
    CalendarEventButton.innerHTML = 'Download Calendar Event';

    CalendarEventButton.addEventListener("click", function() {
      var filename = "CalendarInvite.ics"; //File name that will be downloaded
      download(filename, calendar); //passing in the file name and text to be downloaded
    }, false);

    element.appendChild(CalendarEventButton); //append the button to the document
  }
});


/* Download an embedded file/text*/
function download(file, text) {

  //creating an invisible element
  var element = document.createElement('a');
  element.setAttribute('href',
    'data:text/calendar;charset=utf-8, ' +
    encodeURIComponent(text));
  element.setAttribute('download', file);

  // Above code is equivalent to
  // <a href="path of file" download="file name">

  document.body.appendChild(element);

  //onClick property
  element.click();

  document.body.removeChild(element);
}
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69193332/how-can-i-add-onclick-or-eventlistener-while-appending-a-button-using-javascript Does this answer your question?

Comment: You can try append the button to the document first and then add the event listener, `element.appendChild(CalendarEventButton);`

Comment: Can you post the full userscript?

Comment: I found that if I do not append the text of the invite after I add the button, then the download works. I am still unsure why.
https://pastebin.com/5zLsCTtA

Comment: I rearranged some parsing and removed the piece that was breaking it. I still don't know why it broke.
https://pastebin.com/chpExuZb

Comment: I'm more interested in which page the userscript runs. There's no way I can reproduce your problem if I don't have that info.

Comment: It is not a public source, but here is the piece of the page that it works on:
https://pastebin.com/7mc0YhTj

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Used `const` (ES2015+) instead of `var` (<= ES5).
2. Cloned the element in order to remove the `div.clearfix` in a more reliable way.
3. Used template strings (`....`).
4. Used native [`GM_download` method](https://www.tampermonkey.net/documentation.php#GM_download) for easier/reliable downloading.

```js
// .....
// @grant        GM_download
//=====    convert text only calendar to a donwloadable ICS file
elementReady('#desc-content').then((element) => {
  // grab the relevant text
  const cloned = element.cloneNode(true);

  if (!cloned.innerText.includes("BEGIN:VCALENDAR")) return;

  // clean up some bit

  // use the cloned element so that removing clearfix div
  // won't affect DOM
  cloned.querySelector('.clearfix')?.remove();
  const calendar = cloned.innerHTML.replace(/<br\s*[\/]?>/gi, '\n');

  // Create a button element 
  const calendarEventButton = document.createElement("button");
  calendarEventButton.innerHTML = 'Download Calendar Event';

  calendarEventButton.addEventListener("click", function() {
    const filename = "CalendarInvite.ics"; // File name that will be downloaded

    download(filename, calendar); // passing in the file name and text to be downloaded
  }, false);

  element.appendChild(calendarEventButton); //append the button to the document
});


/* Download an embedded file/text*/
function download(file, text) {
  const encoded = encodeURIComponent(text);
  const downloadable = `data:text/calendar;charset=utf-8, ${encoded}`;

  GM_download(downloadable, file);
}
```